# How to search an array of objects and then update a part of the object in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an Array of objects. Each object is a customer record, which is the customer ID (int), first name (String), last name(String), and balance (double).

My problem is that i am not supposed to have duplicate customer records, so if they appear in the file twice, I have to just update their balance. I cannot figure out how to search the array to find out if i need to just update the balance or make a new record in the array.

I feel like i should do this in the get/setters, but i am not exactly sure.

edit: to clarify on "**if they appear in the file twice, I have to just update their balance.**" I have a file i made in notepad which is supposed to be a customer list, which has all of their information. if the same customer shows up twice, say the following day to buy more stuff, i am not supposed to create a new object for them since they already have an object and a place in the array. instead, i am supposed to take the amount they spent, and add it to their already existing balance within their existing object.

edit2: i thought i would give you the bit of code i have already where i read in the values into the array. i based this off of the example we did in class, but we didn't have to update anything, just store information into an array and print it if needed.

```
public CustomerList(){
    data = new CustomerRecord[100]; //i'm only allowed 100 unique customers
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Records.txt"));
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
            data[i] = new CustomerRecord();
            data[i].setcustomerNumber(input.nextInt());
            data[i].setfirstName(input.next());
            data[i].setlastName(input.next());
            data[i].setTransactionAmount(input.nextDouble());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you use different data structure? can you please clarify **"if they appear in the file twice, I have to just update their balance."**  too?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `arrays` in that case. A [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) would be much more suitable as it, by definition, does not have duplicate entries.

What you need to do is to implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in your `Customer` class so they only use `id` (or `id` and `name` fields) but not `balance`.

**If** for some reason you need to use arrays you have two options:

- sort the array and use binary search to find if the customer is there, this is nice if the array doesn't change much but you're doing a lot of updates
- simply do a linear scan of the array, checking each entry to see if a given customer is already there, if so then update the balance, otherwise add it as a new entry

It would be something like:

```
public void updateOrAdd(Customer cst) {
  boolean exists = false;
  for(Customer existing : array) {
    // !!! You need to implement your own equals method in the
    // customer so it doesn't take into account the balance !!!
    if(existing.equals(cst)) {
      exists = true;
      existing.updateBalance(cst.getBalance());
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!exists) {
    // add the cst to the array
  }
}
```

The difference is in runtime, the set solution will be constant O(1) on average (unless you incorrectly implement your `hashCode()` method).

Comment: it seems the op cannot use any data structures other than array

Comment: @KickButtowski hence the second part of my answer :-)

Comment: yes, sorry i just got to answering. i am not allowed to use anything else as i haven't gone over how to use sets in class. we are just getting into oop, and still trying to figure out everything. so if i am understanding correctly, i should input those lines of code in right after i read in the Customer ID?

Comment: @lilranford yes you read in your customer from the file (this creates a Customer object) and then you pass it to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `Customer` array:

```
Customer[] customers = new Customer[size];
... // fill the array with data
```

Then you get a new customer object called `newCustomer`. You need to search for `newCustomer` in your array and, update it if it is already there, or add it if it's not. So you can do something like this:

```
// Return, if it exists, a customer with id equal to newCustomer.getId()
Optional<Customer> existingCustomer =
    Arrays.stream(customers)
          .filter(c -> newCustomer.getId().equals(c.getId()))
          .findFirst();
if (existingCustomer.isPresent()) {
    // update the customer object with newCustomer information as appropriate
    Customer customer = existingCustomer.get();
    // assuming you have an updateBalance() method
    customer.updateBalance(newCustomer.amountSpent());
} else {
    // if the customer is not in the array already, add them to the current position
    customers[currentIndex] = newCustomer;
}
```